# Как установить PhpSpreadsheet без использования composer?

Tags: php, xls

Мне нужно перевести xls файл в таблицу mysql с помощью php, погуглив я нашёл данную библиотеку, есть её старая версия - phpexcel, но она как то странно работает с моими xls файлами - с одним всё хорошо отрабатывает, с другим не работает хотя данные аналогичны.
Если без composer никак то может есть какие нибудь другие средства для этого?

Comment: Совсем без композера не выйдет. Можно установить отдельно, но все равно в папке библиотеки придется запустить `composer install`, чтобы установить зависимости в её локальный `vendor`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а руками скачать зависимости никак, или что?

Comment: так зависимости через композер ставятся. SpreadSheet ищет autolod.php либо в своих локальных папках, либо в проекте, иначе _Composer autoloader could not be found. Install dependencies with `composer install` and try again_

Comment: с другой стороны, на своем рабочем компе можете поставить зависимости локально и закинуть вместе с папкой `vendor` на прод (если там нет возможности запускать composer)